# Garlic.js Store date and time when item stored

Tags: javascript

Garlec.js has an `onPersist` function. How can I add also the date and time of the stored item?
I copied this line:

```
this.options.onPersist(this.$element, this.getVal());
```

and added:

```
this.options.onPersist(this.$element, new Date().getTime());
```

But there is no result (and no error messages)